# .apk file in ArcGIS appstudio

Tags: qt, qt-creator, arcgis

I am trying to build ARMv8 APK (64bit) using ArcGIS AppStudio (qt creator). I have all necessary keys to build, I am getting folder after build as "Project" where all build files are generating but I am NOT getting .apk file anywhere.
Can someone let me know where is .apk file located

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I followed procedure as mentioned in - https://doc.arcgis.com/en/appstudio/extend-apps/signyourapp.htm, but now I am unable see final output .apk file , so how to locate .apk file?